# How do you link to a route inside a Symfony form class?

Tags: forms, routes, symfony1, hyperlink, validation

How do you insert a link_to into the 'invalid' message of a regular Symfony form? My form extends the sfGuardUserForm:

```
class SignupForm extends sfGuardUserForm
{
  public function configure()
  {

    ...

    new sfValidatorPropelUnique(array('model' => 'sfGuardUserProfile', 'column' => array('email')), array('invalid' => 'This email address is already in use. Use the forgot password function if you lost your password.'))

    ...

  }
}
```

I would like to link the text 'forgot password' to the @forgot_password route from the applications routing.yml. How would this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `link_to()` function to achieve this. You will have to load the UrlHelper first. This can be done before declaring your form class, like this:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('Url'));
```

Comment: I had to also load the Tag helper before being able to use link_to() in the validator message.

    sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('Url', 'Tag'));

Thanks for the help.